# Setting ANDROID_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Could anybody post a working solution for setting `ANDROID_HOME` via the terminal?

My path to the Android-SDK is `/Applications/ADT/sdk`.

Comment: [Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59153177/5788247) ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME in MAC

Answer (score 644, accepted):

Where the Android-SDK is installed depends on how you installed it.

1. If you downloaded the SDK through their website and then dragged/dropped the Application to your Applications folder, it's most likely here:

   `/Applications/ADT/sdk` (as it is in your case).
2. If you installed the SDK using Homebrew (`brew cask install android-sdk`), then it's located here:

   `/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/{YOUR_SDK_VERSION_NUMBER}`
3. If the SDK was installed automatically as part of Android Studio then it's located here:

   `/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/Library/Android/sdk`

Once you know the location, open a terminal window and enter the following (changing out the path to the SDK to be however you installed it):

```
export ANDROID_HOME={YOUR_PATH}
```

Once you have this set, you need to add this to the PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Lastly apply these changes by re-sourcing .bash_profile:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

4. Type - echo $ANDROID_HOME to check if the home is set.

`echo $ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: I have this and still the same error. 

export HOME="/Users/rover"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Documents/Dev/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/bin/ant"
#export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"

  $ which ant
/usr/local/bin/ant
  $ ls /usr/local/bin/ant
/usr/local/bin/ant

$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4

$ cordova --version
4.0.0

error is: node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e;

Comment: see @kip2's updated answer below ... (uses `tools` not `bin`)

Comment: `export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/ADT/sdk ` - You should explain this thinking....

Comment: hey it keeps restarting everytime... how can I add it permanently on ubuntu?

Comment: If using *brew* you have a generic link to android home if you set ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk without using explicity version number in the path

Comment: @user1735921 You can add the lines you want to run every time you start a new shell to your shell's config file. With the bash shell that would be e.g. ~/.bashrc .

Comment: If you need platform tools install them with `android update sdk --no-ui --filter 'platform-tools'`

Comment: In order to be able to use sdkmanager ,you should add also in PATH ... :$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

Comment: The only tutorial works for me, hold my upvote champs

Comment: On my mac I had to not only install Android Studio but I had to start it up and let it complete it's setup (this took a few minutes). Then go to "Configure" and "SDK Manager" and install the build tools. It was the first selection in the list "Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc1" and click apply. Then copy the "Android SDK Location" path and set it as my ANDROID_HOME in .bash_profile. My builds worked after that.

Comment: except of @oikonomopo s comment , I didn't see anywhere saying to add $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin to PATH, but it is also in my case that sdkmanager is under $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin. I installed Android Studio on mac by downloading the dmg file

Comment: UPDATE. If you installed the SDK using Homebrew ( brew **install** **--cask** android-sdk ), then it's located here:

/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/{YOUR_SDK_VERSION_NUMBER}

Comment: The answer is either needlessly sourcing bashrc, or forgetting to mention that these lines need to be written into bashrc. As it stands, nothing changes in bashrc, so no need to source it.

Answer (score 204):

In Terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Check it worked:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: Also for me. BTW, the 2nd and 3rd lines could be joined in
`export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH`

Comment: For some reason when I run `echo $PATH`, it doesn't output the latest dirs I saved in .bash_profile.

Comment: @Maid786 It's in the home folder, but it is invisible. You can show invisibles in Finder as discussed here http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-funter-3520878/ or use a text editor like TextWrangler that has an option to show invisible files in the file open dialog box.

Answer (score 53):

Adding the following to my .bash_profile worked for me:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: The important point to note that the installation path is /Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 38):

I am having **MAC OS X(Sierra) 10.12.2**.

I set **ANDROID_HOME** to work on **React Native**(for Android apps) by following the following steps.

- Open Terminal (press **Command+SpaceBar**, type **Terminal**, Hit **ENTER**).
- Add the following **3** lines to **~/.bash_profile**.

  ```
    export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
  ```
- Finally execute the below command (or **RESTART** the system to reflect the changes made).

  `source ~/.bash_profile`

That's it.

Comment: @SteveLuck you can create it if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: **@SteveLuck** If you don't find then just create it using **touch ~/.bash_profile** then finally add your content here. You can also create it directly using **vi/vim ~/.bash_profile** then paste the lines. Most of the times you will only find **~/.profile**, you can add here too.

Comment: @SteveLuck `~` is a shortcut for your home folder. If you do not know where is your home folder, type `cd` on the terminal. Typing cd will take you to your home folder. then you can do `vi .bash_profile` or `nano .bash_profile` to open/edit the file.

Comment: Thank you for the update of what you tried and got. It supports the answer.

Comment: What is Command+R supposed to do? Which app do you expect to be in? In Finder that shortcut maps to "Show Original" for an alias? Did you mean Command+Space?

Comment: @uliwitness you are right. Thanks (that was a minor mistake from my side, accidentally re-modified, I guess).

Answer (score 36):

quoting @user2993582's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/1145905)

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

The 'bin' part has changed and it should be

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 26):

I'm using React Native with Catalina mac os and zsh shell

1- touch ~/.zshrc

2- open ~/.zshrc

3- according to [React Native android setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) copy and past

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

to the opened text file then save and close the file.

4- run source ~/.zshrc
and make sure to restart your terminal.

5- run adb you will get something like

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 30.0.0-6374843

thanks for this [documented](https://inthetechpit.com/2020/05/04/setup-react-native-for-ios-and-android-on-mac-with-vs-code/)

**update1 16/2/2021**

this solution works with Big Sur as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer for macOS Big Sur as well. Catalina and later uses zsh instead of bash for new accounts.

Comment: @uliwitness thank you, right I update the answer for Big Sur as well.

Comment: Thanks. this solution works with Monterey too

Answer (score 12):

> Could anybody post a working solution for doing this in the terminal?

`ANDROID_HOME` is usually a directory like `.android`. Its where things like the Debug Key will be stored.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android
```

You can automate it for your login. Just add it to your `.bash_profile` (below is from my OS X 10.8.5 machine):

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-07-19 at 20:21:05
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

# Android
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android

export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/":"$PATH"
```

According to David Turner on the NDK Mailing List, both `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` need to be set because other tools depend on those values (see [Recommended NDK Directory?](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ)).

After modifying `~/.bash_profile`, then perform the following (or logoff and back on):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: i am also facing the same issue but not able to resolve it. Could you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891631/cordova-buildtoolsversion-is-not-specified-macos

Answer (score 11):

To set `ANDROID_HOME`, variable, you need to know how you installed android dev setup.

If you don't know you can check if the following paths exist in your machine. Add the following to `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, or `.profile` depending on what you use

If you installed with homebrew,

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

Check if this path exists:

If you installed android studio following the website,

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

Finally add it to path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If you're too lazy to open an editor do this:

```
echo "export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 6):

The **ANDROID_HOME** environment is the same as the **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** environment, this means it defines the path to the SDK installation directory.

[Click here to about more](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables).

I set up the Android SDK separate from android studio, it gives me more control of where things are.

- First, I download the Android SDK ([Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools)) from the official website.

```
cd $HOME/Downloads
curl https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-7302050_latest.zip --output android-sdk.zip
```

- Second, I unzip the file in the Downloads directory, this process will generate a directory called *cmdline-tools*.

```
unzip android-sdk.zip
```

- Third, I create a directory called android in the **local** directory.

  (`/usr/local` system-wide, read-only files installed by the local administrator, usually you)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/android
```

- Fourth, I move the directory generated by decompression to the android directory renaming it to **sdk**. (In the future I will add the *ndk* directory beside the *sdk*)

```
sudo mv cmdline-tools /usr/local/android/sdk
```

- Fifth, I manually add the environment variables to the `.zshrc` file in my personal directory.

```
nano $HOME/.zshrc
```

```sh
# ...

# Set environment variables for Android SDK
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

# Insert executable file paths in PATH environment variable
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of correct answers here. However, one item is missing and I wasn't able to run the emulator from the command line without it.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator       # can't run emulator without it
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

So it's a compilation of the answers above plus a solution for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86).

And if you use `zsh` (instead of `bash`) the file to edit is `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Setup **ANDROID_HOME** , **JAVA_HOME** enviromental variable on **Mac OS X**

Add In **.bash_profile** file

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

---

For Test

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

Paying it forward for the next lazy / time-crunched person.

I wanted to be lazy and find a Bash script here; there wasn't. So I decided it was time to learn and now here it is.

```
#! /bin/bash

# This script will download the Android command line toools to a path of your choosing.
#
# Syntax  : <cmd> <zip> <path>
#
# Example : run with ./get-cli.sh commandlinetools-mac-8512546_latest.zip /usr/local/android
#
# For the latest .zip matching your system visi:
#
#   https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools 
#
# Note: supplying no args will default to the example
# 
# Respectfully,
#   -Tricknology
#

# command-line-tools zip
cmd_line_tools=$1

# directory to add it to 
android_home_dir=$2

# use defaults if none specified
if [[ cmd_line_tools=="" ]]; then
    #default to aarch64
    cmd_line_tools='commandlinetools-mac-8512546_latest.zip'
fi

if [[ android_home_dir=="" ]]; then
    #statements
    android_home_dir='/usr/local/android'
fi

url=https://dl.google.com/android/repository/"$cmd_line_tools"

###############  gist #########################
# create dir /usr/local/android
# sudo mkdir /usr/local/android

## move tools to usr/local/
# sudo mv cmdline-tools /usr/local/android/sdk

## Set environment variables for Android SDK
# export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android/sdk
# export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

## Insert executable file paths in PATH
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
# export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
################ end gist #######################

# Create directory 
# going to ask for password to create this
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo creating directories
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
    [[ -f "$cmd_line_tools" ]] && { 
        echo creatig dir:  $android_home_dir; 
            sudo mkdir $android_home_dir;
        } || echo $android_home_dir exists;
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo downloading from: $url
echo               to: $android_home_dir
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
     curl $url --output $cmd_line_tools
echo 
echo done
echo unzipping       : $cmd_line_tools
    unzip $cmd_line_tools
echo done
echo 
echo moving to       : "$android_home_dir"/sdk

    [ -d "$android_home_dir"/sdk ] &&
    {   echo "$android_home_dir"/sdk already exists!;
        echo cleaning up : $cmd_line_tools;
            sudo rm $cmd_line_tools;
        echo cleaning up : cmdline-tools;
            sudo rm -rf "cmdline-tools";
        echo exiting!;
        exit -1;
    };
    sudo mv cmdline-tools "$android_home_dir"/sdk
echo
echo done
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo " Setting Environment Variables (Global)"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
    echo setting ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$android_home_dir/sdk
        export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$android_home_dir/sdk
        echo $(export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT)
    echo setting ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
        export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
        echo $(export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME)
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo current path: $PATH
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
    ah_bin=$ANDROID_HOME/bin
    ah_tools=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
    ah_tools_bin=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
    ah_plat_tools=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    [ $(grep -q "$PATH" $ah_bin) ]         && echo $ah_bin exists          || export PATH=$PATH:$ah_bin
echo $PATH
echo
    [ $(grep -q "$PATH" $ah_tools) ]       && echo $ah_tools exists        || export PATH=$PATH:$ah_tools
echo $PATH
echo
    [ $(grep -q "$PATH" $ah_tools_bin) ]   && echo $ah_tools_bin exists    || export PATH=$PATH:$ah_tools_bin
echo $PATH
echo
    [ $(grep -q "$PATH" $ah_plat_tools) ]  && echo $ah_plat_tools exists   || export PATH=$PATH:$ah_plat_tools
echo $PATH
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo setting path to  : $PATH
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
     export PATH=$PATH
echo done
echo 
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo cleaning up 
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
echo removing $cmd_line_tools
     sudo rm $cmd_line_tools
echo done
echo
echo removing "cmdline-tools"
     sudo rm -rf "cmdline-tools"
echo done
echo
echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
echo
echo finished!
echo let ne show you the PATH $(echo $PATH) 
3cho
3cho congratulations on your new ANDROID_HOME=$(echo $ANDROID_HOME)
exit 0
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

People, note that if you will use `~/.bash_profile` then it will edit not your user's bash profile, but global. Instead go to your users directory (/Users/username) and edit it directly:

```
vim .bash_profile
```

And insert following two lines with respect to your Username and SDK directory

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: You are wrong. A file path starting with `~/` means that it is a file in the user's home directory.

Comment: ~ means current user home. So technically this answer is wrong.

Comment: Just erase this answer. For proof, go to any directory on your machine, then type `cd ~; ls` and see what that prints.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open base profile :

```
open  ~/.bash_profile
```

2) Add below line in base profile :

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3
```

Save and close base profile.

For me 27.0.3 working great.