# How to install Android Target for use in Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to cordova and following instructions in ["Create your first App"](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)

I am getting **Android target: not installed**

```
PS D:\xxx\xxxxx\hello> cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.2
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.10.1\bin\gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: not installed
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple macOS
Some of requirements check failed
```

So far, I have installed (and started) Android Studio, which downloaded and installed SDKs and Tools.
Used SDK Manager to install further SDK upto API level 24
Set up environment variables etc.

**How can I install Android Target?**
I am using Window 10.

Comment: this might be due to version mismatch .you can try (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013061/please-install-android-target-android-21)

Comment: After reverting to Java jdk 8 from Java jdk 11 the problem is solved.