# error building android ionic project

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an example project from ionic.
When I run the following the code, I get an error:
`ionic build android`

I get this error ; 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Can someone tell me what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps:

1. `ionic platform remove android`
2. `ionic platform add android`
3. `ionic build android`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the platform? In this working Mac or Windows? If you add ANDROID_HOME mac ?, If you add windows to your PATH location of the SDK?

[Config Android_home osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

[Config IONIC Android APP WINDOWS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLX2FEg0TjU)