# Errors When Installing Android Studio on Windows 7 - Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, windows-7-x64

I extremely new to Android Studio.

After installing it, I started a new project. When the project opened, I got a Gradle sync error:

`Error:Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\gradle\gradle-2.8'`

I started googling around for solutions. I've tried numerous solutions such as deleting the `.gradle`  file, re-installing the program, invalidating cache and restarting and I then tried installing gradle separately. Entering the `gradle` command got me this error message:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext cannot be cast to org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLoggerContext
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.configure(Slf4jLoggingConfigurer.java:42)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:52)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:39)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:199)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:62)
            at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:31)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
            at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
            at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
            at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
            at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

I've looked around the internet but have not found any solutions for these errors. The closest I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602258/cannot-use-android-studio-on-mac-due-to-gradle-solved-after-6-hours). That question was for Macs and I'm on Windows 7. According to the post, the user never got Android Studio to work.

Versions:

- Android Studio: 1.5.1
- OS: Windows 7
- Java: 1.8.0_73
- Gradle: 2.8

My build.gradle file:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
    common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I'd appreciate any and all help to get Android Studio up and running.

Comment: Android Studido to 2.0 ,Gradle to 2.11 ,Gradle Plugin to 2.0

Comment: @tinysunlight How do I upgrade to 2.0? All I'm finding is a 2.0 preview. It's not even a full IDE image. Do you recommend any alternatives? I found gradle 2.11. I was unable to find Gradle Plugin 2.0. Do you mean Android Plugin for Gradle? If so, they're on version 1.5. Do you recommend any alternatives for the Gradle Plugin?

Comment: Yes. Android Plugin for Gradle 2.0.Now you can get Android Studio 2.0 beta.

Comment: I see common to all sub-projects/modules. in your build.gradle. Can you comment it out?