# How to set android path in mac ? when writing the script for appiium

Tags: macos, appium

Please give me quick solution to this am using Mac 10.10 by launching the server am getting below exception.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 807 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have received provides you detailed info what you have to do. You should set the ANDROID_HOME environment.

There is similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x) to your problem.

After that also please check in Appium's Android settings if Android SDK Path is provided.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.bash_profile` add a line for an ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Something like..
`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`

If that is where you installed you android sdk.

You will need to source you bash profile or close and reopen your terminal.

Then you can run `Appium-doctor` to see if all is good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal and Navigate to Home Directory.
2. Execute command open -e .bash_profile and set the path as shown below:

[image]