# Cordova Build fails, buildToolsVersion is not specified

Tags: android, cordova, build, build-tools

This is the exact error I've been getting;

```
F:\XXX\XXX\XXX\myApp-1>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=L:\android-sdks
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configur
ation failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:17
6)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.jav
a:599)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.ja
va:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.ja
va:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatc
h(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatc
h(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java
:83)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java
:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocat
ionHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfte
rEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:504)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBu
ild.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(
WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute
(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execut
e(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(For
wardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClien
t.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBu
ild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(Da
emonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.
run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(Daemon
StateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecut
orImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'F:\XXX\XXX\XXX\myApp-1\platforms\android\Cordova
Lib\cordova.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> cordova_9wgvcsxf5r9stvckgd0tfi8q2$_getAvailableBuildTools_closure3

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.712 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""F:\XXX\XXX\XXX\myApp-1\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "F:\XXX
\XXX\XXX\myApp-1\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.
daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

I've read the different solutions posted for this issue here, and for me simply applying

```
cordova platforms remove android
```

then

```
cordova platforms add android
```

used to fix it, but now not even that is working. The frustrating part is I have two projects on my same computer that I've been updating together and one builds while the other doesn't. So I can't blame the ANDROID_HOME or the like. When I say this I mean:

```
F:\XXX\XXX\XXX\myApp-2>Cordova build android
```

Works perfectly.

Any thoughts? Did I do something to ruin my project somehow? I'm sure both configs are similar but if someone can point me the right way I would be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it as follows:-

Open Android studio configuration.

Go to config>SDK Manager>Android SDK>SDK Tools and install Android SDK Build-Tools.

Check the ANDROID_HOME variable. I am on mac, so it points to `"/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/"`. If you are on other system you need to find out the correct path.

If not set correctly set it as follows:-

`export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/"`

Now build it again and it should work fine

> If you have **not** installed android studio the path can be different and you need to find out the actual path. I would recommend installing Android Studio as it makes things lot easier.

Comment: how to set android_home in mac. I am getting same error. Not able to fix it.

Comment: you need to find out the path to your android sdk and then you can use `export ANDROID_HOME` command to set the path. Please refer to this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I tried have a look into this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891631/cordova-buildtoolsversion-is-not-specified-macos

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my android-versionCode was `25.0.3`

like this in `config.xml` file

```
<widget android-versionCode="25.0.3" id="zakdev.projects.com" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

And i changed it to `25` and it works 
Like this :

```
<widget android-versionCode="25" id="zakdev.projects.com" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `versionCode` works like you're hoping it does https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by re-cloning the repo with my project. If it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issues by saving the build.gradle and/or the build-extras.gradle with Unix (LF) line endings..

Comment: Why would you make changes to the build.gradle file. This is automatically generated in the build folder.