# Cordova: buildToolsVersion is not specified (MacOS)

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting below error while running `cordova build android --release`

```
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
```

it seems like buildToolsVersion is not specified.

Here is the Android_Home which is used by Cordova.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/latest
```

Basically I am trying to change this path with below, but it is not changing the path in Cordova build.

I am using below command to change the path.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

source .bash_profile
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

but it is not changing the path in Cordova.

**Edit:** I also tried to remove and add android platform in Cordova.

**Edit 2:** If I use the same terminal then path of android_home is changed. Seems like bashrc is not updating.

But now I am getting different error and build getting failed.

```
platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/file/FileUtils.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
```

I have installed sdk build tool version 19.1.0, 23.0.1 and 26.0 but still I am getting the error.

**Edit 3**: **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
```

**Edit 4:** Now my Android and Java path are below.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run `cordova build android` I am getting below error.

```
com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.classOrInterfaceOrEnumDeclaration(JavacParser.java:3226)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [`Cordova Android GitHub repo`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/) and [searching it for `buildToolsVersion`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/search?q=buildToolsVersion), you'll see in `build.gradle` the Android `buildToolsVersion` is currently set for `23.0.1`

Click on the search link above, and try installing the Android Build Tools version shown for the file `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with same configuration 2 days ago it was working fine.

Comment: i am adding content of build.gradle

Comment: I have installed the 23.0.1 sdk tools but it is still failing with same error.

Comment: I have the Android SDK installed via Brew also. My `ANDROID_HOME` is different that what you have above. In my `.bash_profile` I have
`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

Comment: do i need to install it via brew?

Comment: I think you already did. Check from the command line. Type `brew ls` and you should see `android-sdk` listed.

Comment: yes  its installed i am getting output ant. I am still not sure what happened. Because it was working fine.

Comment: so try `export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk` and `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/bin` instead of what you have shown in your question above.

Comment: if i use android_home of brew then i am getting this error - No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher. Tried the command which you have given above getting  error 19.1.0 or higher one.

Comment: Then I don't know what to advise you to do, except backtrack your changes to what worked previously.

Comment: well. thanks for your effort. I will check what i can do. It is quite complicated.