# Unable to run Cordova project in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

i have a project with ionic and works fine in browser, but when i try to load it on Android Studio, i import it and then appear a error saying:

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 24.0.1 and sync project</a>
```

If i try to downgrade the version cordoba project not run, weird thing is that according to the IDE i have the correct version of it.

Even in build.grade file

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
```

[image: Trying to load cordoba project in Android Studio]

SDK Manager:

[image]

Comment: try to click on install build tools 24.0.1 and sync project..

Comment: 9:18:21 AM Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: Open the SDK manager? Install the needed API version

Comment: It is installed, says: 

Android SDK Build-tools 24.0.1 Installed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Andorid SDK is installed in the right path

[Setting ANDROID_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1

Its in the right place.