# Android Emulator won't boot or start. Nothing is popping up

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, startup

This question is already many times asked but nothing its like my problem.
I don't get it why its not booting up or starting my apk.

[image: Its stucks right there]

Its stuck right there. Nothing is happening just the waiting for target device respond is coming up.

Everything worked perfectly until now.

I even reinstalled it. Didn't help much

PC SPECS:
i7 Core 2.2 GHZ
16GB RAM
Intel Iris Pro 1500MB

Android Studio 2.3

```
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

Still the same error.....

Comment: setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.

Comment: @JohnJoe tried that already

Comment: @JCD - what happens when you start the Android Emulator from the Android Studio AVD Manager first and have it running and then build your app?

Comment: @JamalEason It's nothing happening. Thats the problem. It won't even show the emulator

Comment: @JCD - to debug this, go to the command line and go to the path of your Android SDK and try these commands: _$ cd [path to Android SDK]/emulator/_  and then run _$ ./emulator -list-avds_  identify the AVD you created, then run _$ ./emulator -avd [name of the avd]_  and look for the output of the emulator. What do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work with changing the auto graphics to software!

Answer (score 2):

I ran the commands that Jamal Eason recommended in the comments:

```
$ cd Android/Sdk/emulator
$ ./emulator -list-avds
$ ./emulator -avd [AVD_NAME]
```

I got some `libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so` errors when trying to run the AVD.

I was able to find [this thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/android-virtual-device-doesnt-show-up/21262/15), where a user was able to fix a very similar issue by renaming the `libstdc++.so.6` inside the emulator directory and linking the `libstdc++.so.6` from the `/usr/` directory.

```
$ cd Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: If `libstdc++.so.6` is not in `/usr/lib64` you can find it by using: 
`locate libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 1):

I wasted some time with the same problem, for me after all, the solution was to power off my vagrant machine, this means that if you have a virtual machine running, is not allowing the AVD to run. So if that's the case, just power off the VM's and try again.

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same exact issue, so I ran the commands suggested by Jamal Eason, and I got the following error.

> PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Did some looking around and found that actually my ANDROID_HOME environment variable was pointing to the incorrect location. So I added the following commands to my ~/.bash_profile to update the ANDROID_HOME variable to point to my Android directory, which for me looked like the following.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{USER_NAME}/.android/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/7745771) for more information on updating the environment variable.

After that, I restarted Android Studio and was able to run my emulator as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Free more space on your disk. The problem may be related to the space left on your hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

try to use another emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) 
and run it manually before runnig your app

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got that already many times but I just need it with the Android Studio Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after manually moving Android SDK to another disk to save disk space on `C:\` and improperly setting `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`.

I set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` to `d:\stuff\android\.android\` whereas it should have been  `d:\stuff\android\`.

Apart from that, since Android machinery was creating another `.android` inside `.android` so I moved its contents one folder up.

Answer (score 0):

Only running emulators that were `x86` worked for me.

(I also edited the emulator settings for that device and selected "automatic" for graphics driver and selected a device as it appeared to be uninitialised).

Also check out the obvious: [Google's page on it](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html)