# How to set up ionic development environment in mac for android and ios

Tags: macos, android-studio, ionic-framework, installation, ionic2

I am new to mac.

I am following this [mac-setup](https://ionicframework.com/docs/resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html) i have completed all the steps as per the document but when i type `android` in my terminal which is the last step i am getting this error

first i have installed ionic framework and nodejs with this command `sudo npm install -g ionic cordova`

then i installed `xcode,java and android studio` from the app store.

then i setup the `environment variable` as per the document

> -bash: android: command not found

any idea what i am doing wrong

Comment: have you installed android sdk and did you configure the path for android?

Comment: no to open android sdk i typed android in my terminal but it is not opening android sdk platform

Comment: refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/2885781
and maybe this link also will help you for android configuration http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html