# Set up the ANDROID_HOME environment variable on MacOS

Tags: android, macos, react-native

I am having trouble setting the Android_Home variable on my MacOS. I have the MacBook Pro 2016 edition. Can't seem to find .profile. I tried to create it but looks like it didn't take. Any thoughts?

Thanks.
-Nathan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting ANDROID\_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 4):

The file is called `.bash_profile` and can be found in your home directory (`/Users/<username>`)

To add your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable there, you would need to add the following line to your `.bash_profile`

`export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk`

To apply the changes, restart your terminal. Confirm that the changes have been applied by typing the following in your terminal:

`echo $ANDROID_HOME`

Your output should be `/path/to/android/sdk` as entered above.

Answer (score 1):

These line should be add to your `Shell Initialization Files`：

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{YourUserName}/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
```

- If you are using `bash` (by default), you should add these lines to your `~.bash_profile` or `~.bashrc`
- If you are using `zsh`, you should add these lines to your `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Old school way to check if `.bash_profile` file exists following could be done:

1. Go to `Finder>Go>COMPUTER>Mac HD>Users`, THEN click on your `user account`.

[image]

2. Now hold down `⌘ + ⇧ + .`, this will now display hidden files and folders. It will look something like this:

[image]

In case the `⌘ + ⇧ + .` does not work, please look up the keyboard shortcut relevant for your Mac Operating system name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up the ANDROID_HOME environment variable on macOS Catalina, .bash_profile is no longer Apple's default shell, and it won't persist your path variables. Use .zprofile instead and follow the environment setup instructions in react-native documentation or others. .bash_profile will keep creating new file which won't make the path permanent or persist on closing the terminal on your system path.

To create a new path just do this in macOS Big Sur:

1. `sudo touch ~/.zshrc`
2. `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
3. export all the path
4. ctrl + x and save
5. `source ~/.zshrc`
6. Check with `echo $PATH`