# Not able to run react-native app in my mobile through usb

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native, facebook-android-sdk

I did what ever explained in the below official link.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

The device is connected and said to trust my connected computer.

But when I run `react-native run-android` it says

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

So, I googled a lot to get it done. Later a solution asked me to create local.properties file and paste `sdk.dir = /home/abc/androidsdk/sdk`. Then I am facing this issue.

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 23, Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

The only thing I want is, running my react-native app in my lenova k4 note mobile.

Comment: well...why not just do what the error says and open the sdk manager?

Comment: @luschn Guide me how.

Comment: you really need to start using google: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Comment: or: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this issue because ANDROID_HOME variable is not set to PATH for setting path variable

for mac use this 
[Setting ANDROID_HOME enviromental variable on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x)

for windows 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

Comment: Hi I am using ubuntu 14

Comment: just google it for adding environment variable or path variable in ubuntu you will get many post