# react native ANDROID_HOME environment variable setup

Tags: macos, react-native, environment-variables, reactive-programming, react-android

I am getting the below error on 'react-native run-android'.. how to fix it?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  **A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable**.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Here the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

Go to your environment variables and add ANDROID_HOME variable with SDK location

[This video might help you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVaGbwQephg)

Comment: i am using mac .so can u pls give the solution for mac

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to folder android then create a file called local.properties and inside this file specify your SDK location. after that open Terminal and type following commands

- Type - echo export "ANDROID_HOME=/Users/yourName/Library/Android/sdk"
- ~/.bash_profile.

That's it