# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' & 'android' command in your 'PATH'

Tags: android, ionic4

I get this error:

> Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

This happens because I have on `.bashrc` the `$ANDROID_HOME` and `$PATH` set up, but when I run `sudo ionic cordova build --release android` doesn't detect it to me. What should I do?

Comment: export PATH=<path_to_android_sdk>/platform-tools:<path_to_android_sdk>/tools:$PATH
add tools also like above

Comment: When using `sudo`, the environment variables change. Try `sudo env`, does it shows the `ANDROID_HOME` ?

Comment: if you're using Mac maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986214/setting-android-home-enviromental-variable-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Finally i've changed the owner (Don't know why i dont have permissions all the time, doing some stuff on Ionic...) I have to change the permissions all time... and it works perfectly! finally was with sudo it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your `sudo` is not configured to keep the `PATH` (see `env_keep` in sudoers). So when running a command using `sudo`, there is not `ANDROID_HOME` defined anymore.

A quick way to find out is to run `sudo env | grep -i android`.

To solve the problem, many ways:

1. change the `sudo` setting so your `PATH` environment variable is left unchanged (using `env_keep` in settings, google is your friend);
2. define the `ANDROID_HOME` variable in `/root/.profile` or `/etc/profile`, etc.
3. etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i solved the problem as i said on the comments :)