# how to compile and run android application using a batch file and not IDE?

Tags: android

How can i compile and run android application using a batch file and not any other IDE? is it  possible to do? and if it is possible, can you teach me how to make a batch file? I don't have any idea to it, I only know how to run id using eclipse ide.  thank you.

Comment: How? Reading the documentation.

Comment: Also, consider using Gradle: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [android doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html), i'll just add debug mode:

### Debug mode

> For immediate application testing and debugging, you can build your
>   application in debug mode and immediately install it on an emulator.
>   In debug mode, the build tools automatically sign your application
>   with a debug key and optimize the package with zipalign.
>
> To build in debug mode:
>
> Open a command-line and navigate to the root of your project
>   directory.
>
> Use Ant to compile your project in debug mode: ant debug
>   This creates your debug .apk file inside the project bin/ directory,
>   named -debug.apk. The file is already signed with
>   the debug key and has been aligned with zipalign. Each time you change
>   a source file or resource, you must run Ant again in order to package
>   up the latest version of the application.
>
> To install and run your application on an emulator, see the following
>   section about Running on the Emulator.

### How to run

> Before you can run your application on a device, you must perform some
>   basic setup for your device:
>
> Enable USB debugging on your device. On most devices running Android
>   3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development. On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer
>   options.
>
> Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden
>   by default.
>
> To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap
>   Build number seven times. 
>   Return to the previous screen to find
>   Developer options.
>
> Ensure that your development computer can detect
>   your device when connected via USB Read Setting up a Device for
>   Development for more information.
>
> Once your device is set up and connected via USB, navigate to your
>   SDK's platform-tools/ directory and install the .apk on the device:
>
> `adb -d install path/to/your/app.apk`
>
> The -d flag specifies that you
>   want to use the attached device (in case you also have an emulator
>   running).

A simple batch for debug mode could be:

```
set PROJECT_ROOT="Your_project_root"
set ADB_LOCATION="Your ADB Location"
set PROJECT_NAME="Your project name"
cd %PROJECT_ROOT%
ant debug
cd %ADB_LOCATION%
adb -d install %PROJECT_ROOT%/bin/%PROJECT_NAME%-debug.apk
```

---

Compile in release mode is a bit more longer, so i would say read the documentation.

Comment: what is adb location?

Comment: it's located in your SDK folder, usually Android SDK\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: add: cd %PROJECT_ROOT% android update project -p (an answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271024/sdk-dir-is-missing-android-update-project)